# How to delete a file that is attached to a variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pdfkit

As a quick summary of this code, this script coverts an .xlsx file into a .pdf file. Afterwards, i intend on deleting the excel file to ensure that the excel file i sunavailable to be tampered with (I have yet to make the .pdf file read only).

```
import pandas as pd
import pdfkit
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import time
import os

os = 'Windows 10'
file_name = 'report_prototype_excel1.xlsx'
company_name = 'ABC Company'
audit_frequency = 'ANNUAL'
file_time = time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")

if os == 'Windows 10':
  config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe')
elif os == "Windows Server 2019":
  print("Placeholder Windows Server 2019")
elif os == "MacOS":
  print("Placeholder MacOS")
else:
  print("Placeholder Ubuntu/Debian")

df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
df = df.fillna(" ")
df.to_html("report_prototype_html1.html")
options = {
    'page-size': 'A4',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
}
pdfkit.from_file("report_prototype_html1.html", company_name + '_' + audit_frequency + '_audit_report_pdf_' + file_time + '.pdf', configuration=config, options=options)
os.remove (file_name)
```

However, since i will be assigning the files to a fixed variable, the "os.remove" command does not work, resulting in this error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\********\Documents\********\********\report_prototype_python_MAIN.py", line 33, in <module>        
    os.remove (file_name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Is there a solution to my predicament?

Answer (score 1):

You have imported `os` module and also assigned a variable `os = 'Windows 10'`. Because, `os` is now a string, it doesn't have `remove` method you are looking for.

Please rename `os` variable to something else.

Answer (score 0):

`os = 'Windows 10'` by this sentence you override the module `os`.
just rename your variable.